# Oauth token encryption and hash

Tags: encryption, oauth, apigee

Once oauth token is generated in api, in the response 
We need to encrypt oauth token, then salt with timestamp and hash it

Using client credentials, the client is hitting apigee. but in response how to encrypt oauth token, then salt with timestamp and hash it?

```
 curl https://{org}-test.apigee.net/oauth/client_credential/
  accesstoken?grant_type=client_credentials -X POST -d 
  'client_id={consumer_key}&client_secret={consumer_secret}'
```

the response is as follows

```
   {  
  "issued_at" : "1382703699776",
   "application_name" : "8586c7b7-2936-4779-b7a6-97014e436d7d",
  "scope" : "READ",
  "status" : "approved",
  "api_product_list" : "[PremiumWeatherAPI]",
  "expires_in" : "3599",
  "developer.email" : "tesla@weathersample.com",
  "organization_id" : "0",
  "client_id" : "SJOaCEGohSu3vpNswMs5YdBlc2GOAh1J",
  "access_token" : "UAj2yiGAcMZGxfN2DhcUbl9v8WsR",
  "organization_name" : "myorg",
  "refresh_token_expires_in" : "0",
  "refresh_count" : "0"
   }
```

in response I need to encrypt the oauth access token and salt with timestamp and then hash it.
How to do that

Comment: Hi @mnvbrtn, can you explain a bit more about the use case? What is the purpose of hashing the access token? Are you not sending the original token in the response?

Comment: yes we are sending the access token back . But once token is generated, they will use this against another api gateway (not apigee), to validate the token. I think they can't verify the token as it is generated by apigee, so the want to validate the hash of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach that you can use:

- Right after the Generate access token policy you would be able to access `oauthv2accesstoken.{policy_name}.access_token` variable. Use an assign message policy to assign this value to a variable.
- Next, for calculating the hash you need to use a java, python or a javascript policy in the response part of the flow. This [link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha256.html) has a sample JavaScript for sha256.